# Keeping the same user and group on files going forward?

Tags: ubuntu, acl, ownership

I'd like for the ownership of all the files on my site to stay as follows:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

But I need to change the files with another user, so I did the following to set ACLs:

```
setfacl -Rdm u:sampleuser:rwx /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

But now, if I upload a new file, that file is owned by sampleuser, not www-data.

Is there any way to keep it as www-data for all files/directories even after I add new files with sampleuser?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Generally, a file will be owned by its creator. In the case of a web application, the creator is usually the web application itself. Here, it sounds like you're uploading a new file with a different user account, so that's what will own the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could enforce the group to always be www-data by setting the sampleuser to that group.

sudo usermod -a -g www-data sampleuser

Now set the default group permissions on any files folders created within:

setfacl -m "default:group::rwx" /var/www/example.com/public_html